# How to Fix: iOS drops CSS files when javascript changes DOM

Tags: javascript, css, ios, dom, innerhtml

I've got a persistent issue specifically in iOS when I alter the document using, innerHTML, appendChild, and removeChild my CSS declarations are completely stripped and I get the no-styles version of the page.

I've not been able to find anything after a several hour google search on anything even remotely close to this. I've not been able to replicate the issue on other mobile devices though I've only tested on an Android Galaxy s2 and iPad 2.

I know it's not specifically safari, as I've tested on a PC all major browsers and the CSS loads completely fine. It's just seeming like its something to do with the iOS implementation of javascript.

Here's a video I recorded of the problem as well (2 mins long):
http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=4573014247189

Edit: I've been able to replicate it on a live site using the bare minimums to duplicate the behavior.
http://mlkart.com/ios_bug

Edit: Found the issue, currently looking for alternatives, will post with solution when it's found, but here's the cause for the trouble in iOS:

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(oldStuff, newStuff);
```

What ends up happening is everything outside of and including the body tag are getting stripped away erroneously. This may be an iOS javascript bug or just a quirk, but as far as I know that should be a valid selector!

Comment: I've done similar work before on iOS but within a UIWebView, not mobile safari.  In my case, the CSS was embedded in the page.

Comment: I'm using the typical <link rel="stylesheet"> method for including my external CSS into the page, though that code never changes between pages, so why it stops working on these pages is beyond me.

Comment: @John Conde: This is not specifically related to mobile safari as I also tested on Mercury browser for iPad 2 and the problem exists there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS, there is an issue with a javascript function implementation regarding "documentElement". Using this code will break your site in iOS environments, but I do not know if this issue is on Oracle's or on Apple's side.

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML = document.documentElement.innerHTML.replace(oldStuff, newStuff);
```

This has been removing everything outside of and including the body tag in my HTML documents in iOS.

My accepted solution has been to replace all occurrences of

```
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

with

```
document.body.innerHTML
```

Solution is tested and appears working in all modern available testing avenues I have access to.

Answer (score 0):

why do not you validate your html in the w3c http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input sometimes when there are errors of html, some browsers correct the error and others do not.

As well the javascript could work in a different way depending on the browser. Once I had a jQuery code perfect in fireFox and not in IE. The error was that I was taking the width of an element but initially this element did not have a width, so for IE it was 0, for fireFox it was depending on the elements inside of this.

Try to test it in safari in your PC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but as I said in my original post I've tested in all major browsers on my PC this includes Safari.